# Regex capturing within a group

Tags: java, regex

I want to be able to delete all instances of newlines within `<p>` tags, but not the ones outside. Example:

```
<p dir="ltr">Test<br>\nA\naa</p>\n<p dir="ltr">Bbb</p>
```

This is the regex I came up with:

```
(<p[^>]*?>)(?:(.*)\n*)*(.*)(</p[^>]*?>)
```

and I replace with:

```
$1$2$3$4
```

I was hoping that this would work but `(?:(.*)\n*)*` seems to be causing issues. Is there any way to do repeated matches like this, with a capturing group?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are two `p` tags? you want `\n` to be removed separately for them?

Comment: Separately for `p` tags is fine. Its just that I'm hoping to replace all the `\n` within the `p` tags in one fell swoop. I was hoping that its possible with regex without nested loops.

Comment: Wouldn't a parser better suit your needs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I would recommend using something like JSoup for this kind of work.

Comment: @ThePerson makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Solution**

You can use this regex(works in PCRE but not in Java. **For Java version refer below**)

```
(?s)(?:<p|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!<\/p>).)*?\K[\n\r]+
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA3wS1/3)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?s) #Enable . to match newlines

(?:
   <p #this part is to assure that whatever we find is inside <p tag
    | #Alternation(OR)
   \G(?!\A) #Find the position of starting of previous match.
)

(?:
  (?!<\/p>). #Till it is impossible to match </p>, match .
)*? #Do it lazily

\K #Whatever is matched till now discard it

[\n\r]+ #Find \n or \r
```

**Java Code**

With a bit of modification, I was able to do it in Java

```
String line = "<p dir=\"ltr\">Test<br>\nA\naa</p>\nabcd\n<p dir=\"ltr\">Bbb</p>"; 
System.out.println(line.replaceAll("(?s)((?:<p|\\G(?!\\A))(?:(?!<\\/p>).)*?)[\\n\\r]+", "$1"));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/YbEYur)**

Comment: Holy... Wow. that's pretty darn amazing.

Comment: damn my regex noobness! good job rock - i was too slow to be the savior.

Comment: @Jun first let me check it in JAVA

Comment: You knew that you can put in [comments in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nA3wS1/2) as well ? Additionally, why put the `\n` in a character class? It's only one character! +1 nevertheless.

Comment: I really need to try to understand your regex now. Its going to be hard :) Thanks!

Comment: @Jun added a bit of explanation..its starter only..you have to read it in detail for full understanding

Comment: @downvoter..please leave a comment before downvoting..this is ridiculous and frustrating

Comment: wasn't me, but my best guess is that it has something to do with "works in PCRE but not Java" ?

Comment: @sweaver2112 whoever it was should have read at least the full answer

Comment: why not just remove the PCRE stuff?  Also, can you explain why your Java solution is "a bit of a hack" ?

Comment: Just was about to add answer `"(?s)\\n+(?=(?:(?!<p).)*?</p)"` as a Java idea when I saw you did update for Java. I like your answer.

Comment: @sweaver2112 I won't remove PCRE stuff because it guided me to the answer..well its not really a hack but if Java supported `\K`, it would have been much easier

Comment: If you want to integrate in answer, I feel honored, else just leave as comment. I go for bed now (:

Comment: @bobblebubble in any case, you should add it..as it is better than mine..:)

Comment: @rock321987 Your pattern is more accurate and if there is a long html input with many `\n` outside of `<p` I think your approach will outperform my idea as mine would trigger the lookahead at any `\n+`.

Comment: @bobblebubble but there is one problem..your pattern does not consider to modify within `p` tag..see **[here](https://regex101.com/r/nA3wS1/4)**..i am removing your update..please make it work?

Comment: @rock321987 You mean it does not check for an opening `<p`? No it doesn't. My pattern expects to get beautiful and valid html to eat (: now the bed calls.